# How to have VBscript essentially run a VLookup on a SQL server by using data from a file name and returning data from 3 columns matching that row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vbscript

I am fairly new to VBscript and have run into a (I'm assuming) unique scenario that I have not been able to crack after hours of searching on here and other forums. This could potentially be valuable to others, as it has the potential to be modified and applied for numerous other uses. The situation is, on a weekly basis, I get statement pdf's (around 500) for multiple statements dumped into a server folder. The first 8 characters in each file name is that unique account number. I need to identify which client that statement is for, and for what sub account. Rename the file into a format "date_accountnumber_client_subaccount".pdf. I then need to locate that clients directory, and move the file there. I have figured out how to move a file, and rename it. But I am having trouble figuring out how to get the VBscripting to connect to our SQL server in order to retrieve the additional data. Basically I need it to pull the account number from the file name, run that account number through column A in the server then when it finds a match, pull the data from column B, column C and column D and assign them to individual objects, so I can reorder the information if needed. I also need to have the routine loop until there are no more statements left in the directory, and move files it can't identify into a "Manual_Review" folder. I know if I can get the data that is associated to the account number from the SQL Server then, I can concatenate the directory path for the file to move to. Below is the limited coding I have as of now. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "\\Company Shared Folders\Operations\Lucas_Mod_Scripting_Test\"

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)


strInput = InputBox("Enter Date (YYYY.MM.DD):", "Enter Date")

Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each objFile in colFiles

Dim Pname 
Dim oFSO 
Dim sSourceFile 
Dim sDestinationFolder
Dim sDestinationName
Dim DestinationFile
Dim LookupSQL

PName = Left(objFile.Name,Len(objFile.Name) - 4)


Select Case Pname
Case "85559664"
    sDestinationFolder = "\\Company Shared           Folders\Operations\Lucas_Mod_Scripting_Test\Moved\"
    sDestinationName = "clientname"

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    sSourceFile = objStartFolder & "\" & objFile.Name
    sDestinationFile = sDestinationFolder & "\" & strInput & " " & Pname & " " &       sDestinationName & Right(objFile.Name, 4) 

    If oFSO.FileExists(sDestinationFile) Then
        Set oFSO = Nothing
    Else
        oFSO.MoveFile sSourceFile, sDestinationFile
        Set oFSO = Nothing
    End If

Case "StatementScriptTest"
Case Else
End Select
Next

Wscript.Echo "Script Complete"
```